# Create a query for database in Hiberante , which is not a entity

Tags: database, hibernate, entity

I am new to `HIBERNATE`. I'm creating a web app in `JSF & Hibernate`. If I have a table in the database which don't have any corresponding java class in my app can I use `Hibernate` to fire a query for such database?

Answer (score 1):

Hey You could also use org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer Interface to convert your fetched objects to an POJO

```
public class MyResultTransformer implements ResultTransformer {

@Override
public List<Employee> transformList(List arg0) {
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    for (Object employee : arg0) {
        employees.add((Employee) employee);
    }
    return employees;
}

@Override
public Employee transformTuple(Object[] arg0, String[] arg1) {
    System.out.println("MyResultTransformer.transformTuple()");
    Employee tempEmp = new Employee();
    tempEmp.setEmployee_id((BigInteger) arg0[0]);
    return tempEmp;
}
```

}

POJO

```
public class Employee {

private BigInteger employee_id;

public BigInteger getEmployee_id() {
    return employee_id;
}

public void setEmployee_id(BigInteger employee_id) {
    this.employee_id = employee_id;
}
```

}

```
  Query query=session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM employeedetail");
     query.setResultTransformer(new MyResultTransformer());
     List<Employee> employees=query.list();
     for (Employee employee : employees) {
         System.out.println(employee.getEmployee_id());
    }
```

It's the best way I found to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hey instead of using HQL you can create a SQL query

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
     SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
     Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
     List<Object[]> lists=session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM employee ").list();
     for (Object[] employee : lists) {
        System.out.println(employee[0]+"  "+employee[1]);
    }
```

This will give you a list of Array of  Objects. Your can use this array to get values of your query.

I hope this will help you.